# Sign Conventions in Mirror/Lens formula

Tags: optics, reflection, conventions, lenses

All textbooks I've come across have the same way of *proving* the mirror formula. Everything makes sense, except the fact that they apply the sign convention once to obtain the mirror/lens formula, but when they use the formula to solve a question, they apply the sign convention again. Why?

Comment: More on [sign conventions in optics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+sign*+convention*+optics).

Comment: @Qmechanic ♦ Still confused...

Comment: For me it's not clear what are you asking. In particular, what you mean with "but when they use the formula to solve a question, they apply the sign convention again".

Answer (score 1):

This double application of the convention adopted is fundamental to use the formula you derived to make useful predictions.

In fact, quantities involved in such demonstrations (I assume you are talking about geometrical optic, aren't you?) need a convention in order to account for the reciprocal position of two points. If you stated that some quantity is positive in a certain direction in the demonstration of a certain formula, then when it comes to apply this formula you necessarily have to use the same convention, in order to this formula to be valid and useful to make predictions (i.e., solve exercises).

Comment: Yes I'm talking about Geometric Optics. Unfortunately your answer doesn't seem to clear my doubt:(

Comment: @KunalPawar Sincerely, I don't know how to answer differently. I think your doubt is legitimate. I think it could be clearer if you try to derive the formula with one convention and apply it with another one to find out the inconsistencies it brings to.

Comment: That's kinda working backwards... I tried it once... baffled me even more.

Comment: @KunalPawar I'm trying to think again to my answer. Maybe I have not completely understand your doubt. Could you please try to rephrase it? For me, it is just a matter of consistency in the development of a theory and in its application.

Comment: It's just that if I already applied the sign convention. Why apply it again?

Comment: @KunalPawar I think it is like the equation is a sort of "black box" where you put information in (the values of the variables) and you get information out (the value of another variable). By applying the sign convention the first time, you are specifying to your "box" part of the meaning of the incoming information. Then, when putting in the information, you have to be consistent to what you have done (an analogy could be that if you have written a computer program that expects to receive an integer as an input, you have to give it an integer). Then, the information you get will be...

Comment: ... consistent to that sign convention, so you have to apply it another one to interpret it. Again with the "programming analogy", you could have a priori decided that an integer means the value of a certain variable while 9.999 means that an error occurred, and so on. You have to interpret your output with your convention.